# Switch images using timer (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uipageviewcontroller

I use the `UIPageViewController` to show images. I need a timer to show the images one after another, after every 5 seconds. How do I initiate an event to move to the next image after 5 seconds using the timer?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Timer.publish`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/3329589-publish) to create a timer instance field like so:

```
let images = [...] // Array of image names to show
@State var activeImageIndex = 0 // Index of the currently displayed image

let imageSwitchTimer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common)
                            .autoconnect()
```

Then use the [`.onReceive()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3365935-onreceive) modifier of any view to go to the next image:

```
Image(named: images[activeImageIndex])
    .onReceive(imageSwitchTimer) { _ in
        // Go to the next image. If this is the last image, go
        // back to the image #0
        self.activeImageIndex = (self.activeImageIndex + 1) % self.images.count
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have your array using a method @State private var[..].shuffled()

Then encase in your Timer

onReceive method for your timer.
Works a treat